# How to uncompress and import a .tar.gz file in kettle?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to figure out how to create a job/transformation to uncompress and load a .tar.gz file. Does anyone have any advice for getting this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to read a text file that is compressed?

Just specify the file in the text file input step in the transformation - and specify the compression (GZip). Kettle can read directly from compressed files.

If you do need the file uncompressed then use a job step - not sure if there is a native uncompress, but if not just use a shell script step.

Comment: I do not think there is a native uncompress for this. I can do the single .gz uncompress I then end up with the .tar file that needs to be uncompressed again. maybe a two step process with a variable to handle the filename?

Comment: There DEFINATELY is.  Use the "Text File Input" step and set the compression on the content tab.  Best option if you dont want to do anything further with the uncompressed files.

Answer (score -1):

There is not such component in kettle to uncompress the tar.gz file i found.
But if we have the csv file text compressed in gizip format we can use gzip input component.